# Spurious margin on svg element

Tags: html, svg, margin

I have a very simple document (see also [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6K7EX/)):

```
<style>
html, body, svg, div {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}
</style>
<body>
<svg id="foo"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   version="1.1"
   style="width: 768px; height: 1004px;">
</svg>
</body>
```

For some reason, the `svg` element gets a 3px or 4px bottom margin (that is, the `body` element gets a height of 1007px, 1008px or even 1009px; the `svg` margin itself is 0 when inspected using the browser debug tools.)

If I replace the `svg` with a `div`, the spurious margin disappears. The behavior is consistent across Opera 12, Chrome 33, Firefox 26 and Internet Explorer 11, so I'm confident that the behavior is by design and standards compliant, *I just don't get it*.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

This is a common issue with `inline` elements. To solve this, simply add `vertical-align:top`.

[**UPDATED EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/qDw3h/)

```
#foo {
    background: #fff;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

It's worth noting that the default value for the `vertical-align` property is `baseline`. This explains the default behavior. Values such as `top`, `middle`, and `bottom` will correct the alignment.

Alternatively, you could make the element `block` level. [**(example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/eCD4Z/)

Comment: Ah, silly me! I've been thinking of `svg` as a block element. (One of those days, I guess...) I think I'll opt for a `display: block`.

Comment: "Thanks! And, me too!" - I was confused for a few minutes as to why there was a thin margin line when the inspector box model showed no padding or margin anywhere, this was the thing!

Comment: I just added `svg { vertical-align: top }`.  Surprised bootstrap doesn't do this.  The extra margin was completely unexplainable!!!

Comment: I had this kind of problem with `middle`. `top` got rid of most of the extra spacing.

Comment: Thank you so much. It's so frustrating because there's no padding or margins anywhere.

Comment: An alternative solution is to make the parent `display: flex` instead of `display: block`. This avoids showing spurious space below for all chidlren, even if the children have display `inline-block` or `inline-flex`.

Comment: display: 'block'

Answer (score 6):

I had a related problem where I had a div containing an SVG:

```
<div id=contents>
    <svg exported from illustrator>
</div>
```

and there were giant margins above and below the SVG in the DIV, even with vertical-align:top in the DIV and display:block in the SVG.

I had set "width:100%" for the SVG's to make them fill the page.

The solution was to set **"height:100%" for the SVG's**. They were already displaying at the correct height, but adding this got rid of the weird margins.

**I would love to know how and why this worked.**

Answer (score -2):

My document had a single svg element that resized with the window.  I used CSS **overflow:hidden** to prevent scroll bars appearing.
IE:

```
    body {
        overflow: hidden;
    }
```